# MySQL - Limit the amount of rows in a join?

Tags: sql, mysql

Not sure Looking for some guidance here...

I have the following tables:

```
site_text
id   site_id    text    date_added
1    1          ...     2010-02-02 10:01:00
2    1          ...     2010-02-02 10:01:20
3    2          ...     2010-02-02 10:01:00
4    1          ...     2010-02-02 10:01:40
5    2          ...     2010-02-02 10:02:00

sites
id   site_name
1    www.a.com
2    www.b.com
....
```

I'm trying to select the last 2 rows (ordered by date desc) in site_text for each site.  Can you do this with one query?  Something like, but have it only find 2 rows of each site?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM site_text st 
  JOIN sites s ON st.site_id = s.id 
 WHERE st.date_added > '2010-02-01 23:32:04' 
ORDER BY s.id, st.date_added DESC
```

EDIT: In the end, I would be looking for rows 4,2,5,3.

Comment: I don't understand the output you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a clever solution here with CTE's, and `RANK()` `OVER DATE_ADDED` in Pg 8.4 but because you're using mysql, the only thing I can think of of involves a very computationally complex query:

```
-- Select the top date for each site_id
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM site_text
    GROUP BY site_id, date_added
    ORDER BY site_id, date_added
UNION
-- Select the top date for each site_id
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM site_text
    GROUP BY site_id, date_added
        -- Excluding the top date.
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT id FROM site_text
        GROUP BY site_id, date_added
        ORDER BY site_id, date_added
    )
    ORDER BY site_id, date_added
;
```

Moral of the story, use Pg. There might be a more mysql-specific way to do this that yields a more acceptable performance profile.

Comment: Wow, that is expensive.  Thanks for the tips.  I have been meaning to check out PG for a while.  Maybe this is the reason!

Comment: Boy are you in for a treat: it's like coming out of one tunnel of suck.

Comment: With a window function, just for reference, I *think* it would look like this `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT text, date_added, rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY site_id ORDER BY date_added desc ) AS t WHERE t.rank IN (1,2)`, I would expect it to run >100 times faster.